# Looking for better performance in XSLT: xsl:element name="div" vs. <div>

Tags: performance, xslt, xml-parsing

What has more performance in XSLT while writing an XHTML element

```
<xsl:element name="div">
  <xsl:attribute name="class">someclass</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:element>
```

or just write it out

```
<div class="someclass"></div>
```

Does it make any difference in processing-speed / -performance etc. ?

Comment: The latter is certainly more readable!

Comment: That's true. In most cases `readability > performance`

Comment: Results will certainly vary in different processors. In some there will be no difference when no evaluation of element/attribute name occurs. In some there will be difference. See [this link](https://github.com/pasaran/xslt-speed-test/tree/master/attribute-node-vs-inline-attribute) in libxslt context. If this performance impact marginal or not is totally up to you.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer recommending a certain form for writing literal result element with attributes -- there is not a sensible performance gain in any such refactoring, but the readability improvement is huge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspected that XSLT compilers probably convert one into the other internally and, sure enough, at least [some of them](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon7.9/changes.html) do:

> Literal result elements now compile
>   internally into xsl:element and
>   xsl:attribute instructions. This
>   results in changes to trace output:
>   each attribute is now traced as a
>   separate instruction.

More generally, this smells like the kind of micro-optimization that's unlikely to render an improvement that outweighs the benefits of choosing the more readable version.

Comment: Quite. If you've got a performance problem this change isn't going to fix it. If you haven't got a performance problem, why are you worrying about it?

Answer (score 1):

Next to any XSL transformer will map both variants into the same internal representation. Just tested a million calls with saxonb-xslt 9: Absolutely no difference.

Comment: That's certainly true for Saxon - it compiles both into the same internal code. But like all performance questions, it's a question that can only be asked about the specific processor/implementation, not about the language. Note however that the two expressions given are not synonymous: an LRE copies namespaces from the stylesheet, while xsl:element doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Readability is important only in the development cycle. High load sites that use dynamic presentation with XSL will want to shave off seemingly impossible small times.

To test which is faster in your compiler, create two XSL that repeat the same thing 10,000 times and then benchmark the processing speed on the front end. Then divide time difference by 10,000 and you get your true difference in speed.

Depending on the size of the XSL will also have an impact. A fully designed page in xsl:element will be so much larger than straight HTML. However if you use XSL in that method, you should rethink breaking down specific data into XML/XSL includes and the rest of the page templating is done somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

**Whether writing out the element has better performance depends on the XSLT processor.** The processor may optimize the first to have the same performance as the second. Having implemented an XSLT processor, I'd advise that writing the element out instead of using xsl:element is likely to be either as fast or faster, and unlikely to be slower.

Answer (score 0):

**You are not going to obtain any sensible performance gain** from such refactoring (can you feel a microsecond's difference)?

**However, I strongly recommend to use the most readable version**:

```
<div class="someclass"/>
```

Even in the case when the element has attributes whose value is dynamically calculated, **always try to write**:

```
<someElement attr="{someExpression}"/>
```

instead of:

```
<someElement>
 <xsl:attribute name="attr">
  <xsl:value-of select="someExpression"/>
 </xsl:attribute>
</someElement>
```

Comment: I guess you can't rate something in software engineering depending on a human cognition. Even if it's a microsecond. The question is definitely what is more performant. - But I understand your point of view.

Comment: @ChrisBenyamin: You may not respect *my* opinion, but you certainly should respect the opinion of @Michael-Kay (see his comment to the answer of @lwburk). Should I explain who Michael Kay is? Also, remember what another legend (Knuth) said :"*Premature optimization is the root of all evil*".